# Transform a multiclass dataset into a multi-label one

Tags: machine-learning, multiclass-classification, multilabel-classification, labels

I have a dataset of feature/label pairs. My labels are probabilities of each feature vector to belong to the K classes. Here is an example for K = 3:

`D1 = { (V0, [0.33,0.33,0.33]), (V1, [0.9,0.07,0.03]), (V2, [0.5,0.25,0.25])... }`

The probabilities are normalized for a given data point. Yet the task is more a multilabel one, and it would make more sense to have independent Bernoulli distributions e.g.

`D2 = { (V0, [0.9,0.9,0.9]), (V1, [0.99,0.0,0.0]), (V2, [0.9,0.2,0.5])... }`

Is there a trick (smart heuristic) out there which would allow me to transform D1 into D2 based on the way the probability weights are distributed in D1?

Comment: Can you be more specific? How did you exactly got from `(V0, [0.33,0.33,0.33])` to `(V0, [0.9,0.9,0.9])` or from `(V0, [0.9,0.9,0.9])` to `(V1, [0.99,0.0,0.0])`?

Comment: That's the question :)